# Что значат единицы dp в xml раметке Android приложений?

Tags: android

Что значат единицы dp в xml раметке Android приложений?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это density-independent pixels, абстрактные пиксели, зависящие от физического разрешения экрана. При разрешении экрана в 160 dpi абстрактный пиксель равен физическому. При изменении разрешения размер абстрактного пискеля будет пересчитываться пропорционально.

Answer (score 0):

dp: (device-independent pixels) независимые от плотности экрана пиксели. Абстрактная единица измерения, основанная на физической плотности экрана с разрешением 160 dpi (точек на дюйм). В этом случае 1dp = 1px. Если размер экрана больше или меньше, чем 160dpi, количество пикселей, которые применяются для отрисовки 1dp соответственно увеличивается или уменьшается. Например, на экране с 240 dpi 1dp=1,5px, а на экране с 320dpi 1dp=2px. Общая формула для получения количества физических пикселей из dp: px = dp * (dpi / 160)